# Access attributes of another model in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller A (of a model AA) and in it

```
def view_name

end
```

and a model B with:

```
def attributes {
   :a => 'xyz';
}
end
```

How do I access the attribute `:a` inside the view of controller A, so I can display the value of the attribute `:a` in the view page?

More info: Model B has an attribute `:a` which is a url to an image and I have to display the image through the view of controller A. So I'm wondering how to use it in the `<img>` tag. Like `<img src="<%= B.a %>" />`. But wouldn't I have to define B.a as an instance variable in the controller to use it first? Or is there another way?

Comment: Please post full code for the models and controllers, else we won't be able to help you. You can create a gist at github to show the code if you're having trouble displaying in your stackoverflow question: https://gist.github.com/

Comment: I can't, it's propriety code

Comment: If it's proprietary code, and you cannot share more code than you have currently, then I'm giving this a downvote. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Normally if you could access the attribute through an instance of model B.

something like this should work in the view:

```
<% B.each do |test| %>
<p><%= test.a %></p><br/>
<% end %>
```

this would show you of each instance of B the attribute a

but if you would nice if you would add some context it would be much easier to help you.

Comment: Well model B has an attribute ':a' which is a url to an image and I have to display the image through the view of controller A. So I'm wondering how to use it in the <img tag>. Like <img src="<%= B.a %>" />.  But wouldn't I have to define B.a as an instance variable in the controller to use it first? Or is there another way?